# Incorrect cached username for Exchange / Outlook Autodiscover in GPO

Tags: exchange, outlook, autodiscovery, exchange-2016, outlook-2016

I have configured by domain controller with a group policy to "Automatically configure profile based on Active Directory Primary SMTP address". The Autodiscover is working as expected and it connects to my hosted Exchange server.

The issue is that the cached user name is being picked up from the domain, in the following format user@domain.local

Is it possible to control which user name is being passed, so that I can pass a user name in the correct format, which in this case is the primary SMTP address.

PS. I don't want to use a UPN suffix. I want to be able to specify the email logon name independently of changing AD setting.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP address is not a user name. If you want to use it as a username then you'll need to create a UPN suffix that matches the SMTP address and set that as the UPN for your users, there's no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Bu default, Outlook on domain clients can connect to [Exchange Autodiscover](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591328(v=exchg.141).aspx) service with *AutodisscoverInternalURI* setting on CAS servers(by running Get-ClientAccessServ er | fl), regardless of the mailboxes' SMTP Address suffix. So easy. No other additional configuration is needed, and it avoids any other problems caused by additional configurations.

If you have any concern that GPO for autodiscover must be used, you may share it with us, we can try to help or workaround.